# Android NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle error

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

I was setting up a notification in AndroidStudio 1.4.1 and ran into an error with the setStyle function.

This is the code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_assignment)
                .setContentTitle("Easteregg found!");
        String easter = "You found our Easteregg! Well done";
        //custom colour
        int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor);
        builder.setContentText(easter);
        builder.setColor(color);
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle(easter));
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, notification);
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        // Vibration pattern
        long[] pattern = {0, 100, 250, 320};
        v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

When calling

```
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle(easter));
```

I get a notification that

> BigTextStyle could not be applied to java.lang.string

As I used a sample provided by Google https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iog_fmm6mE I am very confused. I also tried out some basic bugfixing but nothing solved the problem, so I am asking you.

If someone could help me with this I would be very thankful.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: If I left something out please bring it up, I'll try to do my best and give you all the information needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code snippet in that video is incorrect. When you run into issues with APIs not performing as expected, I highly recommend [going to the API documentation first](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html#bigText(java.lang.CharSequence)).

In this case, the issue is that there is no constructor for `BigTextStyle` that takes a String. Instead, you need to first create a `BigTextStyle`, then call one (or more) of the three other available methods to set the content.

Something like this is likely what you are looking for:

```
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(easter));
```

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you very much for your answer and the hint with the API documentation!
Here, have a wild flower as a gift. http://wildflower.resn.co.nz/?CodeTillYouDrop+Tanisx